# Derivation of Enthalpy Equation

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

Why are they taking delta H in equation (iv) to be at constant pressure while in the same equation they are considering delta E to be at constant volume to arrive at equation (v)? If they are arriving at equation (iv) from equation (i) then shouldn't P and V be variable?

Comment: I do not understand where the problem is. for a reaction at constant pressure, the use of the ideal gas law allows to go back to the relation (iv)

Comment: Equation (v) is describing the relative heat flows from two different processes, one at constant pressure (where the heat flow at constant pressure, q_p, is given by Delta_H), and one at constant volume (where the heat flow at constant volume, q_V, is given by Delta_E). So it's OK (and, indeed, necessary) to have two different constraints (const. p vs const. V), beause they are comparing heat flows from processes with those two different constraints.

Comment: See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/84207/work-done-by-adiabatic-expansion-of-gas/146588#146588

Answer (score 1):

You determined the $\Delta H$ in going from products to reactants at constant temperature and volume.  But, you are dealing with an ideal gas mixture, so the enthalpy of the product mixture is a function only of temperature, and not pressure.  So the enthalpy change of the product mixture in going from the final pressure in the reactor to the initial pressure is zero.  So, even though it is a constant volume reactor, the enthalpy change you determined also applies to carrying out the reaction at constant temperature and pressure.